# AWS serverless send SMS to user

Tags: amazon-web-services, frontend, sms, serverless

I am trying to build a small web application with AWS but because the services are new to me I am having a hard time. My boss asked that there be a page where the user inserts his phone number before he participating in the research study. After the participant inserted his phone number he will receive 4 text messages (SMS) during the day with a task to perform. The messages will be sent 4 times a day (8:00, 12:00, 16:00, and 20:00) for 10 days, not including Friday and Saturday. could you help me to understand how to approach this project and whether it is possible to do it with AWS?
Thanks in advance,
Orly

Comment: For scheduling messages use AWS Event Bridge service. You'll have your API Gateway (which invokes an API or a Lambda function) and use Event Bridge to schedule your API calls.  You can do something like call SMS sending API using cron expressions as seen here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/scheduled-events.html

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is creating a Simple Notification Service [Topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-create-topic.html) for each new user. Next you would [subscribe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html) the user's phone number to the Topic. You can then [publish](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html) to this Topic the message (under 140 characters) that you want sent.

Answer (score 0):

This use case is very possible with AWS. There are different ways to implement this functionality. To address this use case:

"The messages will be sent 4 times a day (8:00, 12:00, 16:00, and 20:00) for 10 days, not including Friday and Saturday. "

You can build serverless workflows using AWS Step Functions that can perform this use case. AWS Step Functions can invoke many different AWS Services to meet your business needs. For your use case to send a text message, you can invoke the Simple Notification Service.

In fact a workflow can send messages over different channels. Here is a Java based use case that walks you through how to build a workflow that can send messages (including Voice, Email, and Text messages).

[Using AWS Step Functions and the AWS SDK for Java to build workflows that sends notifications over multiple channels](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/workflow_multiple_channels)

As you can see, this workflow reads data in an AWS database to get a result set. For your use case, this sounds applicable.

You can invoke this workflow too from another Lambda function. You can schedule a Lambda function to be invoked x number times a day using CRON expressions as discussed in this document:

[Creating scheduled events to invoke Lambda functions](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_scheduled_events)

Finally, you can build a solution that lets users enter data into a web form and have that data be persisted in RDS or DynamoDB. We have an AWS development article too for that. For example, assume you want to store user data in DynamoDB.

[Creating the DynamoDB web application item tracker](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_dynamodb_web_app)

As you can see, by combing functionality covered in these various AWS tutorials, you can build the solution that you describe.

These articles are implemented by using **AWS SDK for Java V2**. However, if you are working in other programming languages, you need to port the logic to your programming language.